# Extract the index values of DataFrame that are not float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, floating-point, extract

I am working with a DataFrame that is expected to contain only float type index values, but I suspect that for some reason there are values of a different type, resulting in the `dtype='object'` type of the index. I would like to extract the values of the index that are not of the float type to see if this is the case.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}, index=[0.0,1.5,'a'])
```

The result of extraction in this case would be a list containing a single element `['a']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to create a dictionary of types mapped to values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [4,5,6,7,8]},
                  index=[0.0,1.5,'a',pd.to_datetime('10/05/2018'),'b'])

vals = pd.to_numeric(df.index, errors='coerce')
idx = df.index[vals.isnull()]

d = defaultdict(list)

for x in idx:
    d[type(x)].append(x)
```

Then, for example, you can use `d.keys()` to extract all non-numeric types, or `d[str]` to extract indices which are strings.

**Result**

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {str: ['a', 'b'],
             pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp: [Timestamp('2018-10-05 00:00:00')]})
```

Answer (score 4):

Would you want just a way of figuring out what kind of bogus data you have? If so, this is enough.

```
df.index[df.index.str[0].notna()]
Index(['a'], dtype='object')
```

Assuming you have string entries, anything that is not a string will show up as NaN.

If you want to get rid of invalid data, then try coercing it to float, and get rid of NaN rows.

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df.index, errors='coerce').notna()  #.notnull()
df[m]
     a  b
0.0  1  4
1.5  2  5
```

Comment: I would like to investigate what kind of data different than float are there, and if possible of what exact type those data points are.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński You can modify the first line of code as `np.unique(list(map(type, df.index[df.index.str[0].notna()])))` to return something like `[str, ...]`

Comment: Is it only able to handle string types?

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński No should work for anything. `str` was what I typed because that's what is in the example you've given.

Answer (score 3):

Use `isinstance` with `map`:

```
idx = df.index[(df.index.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, float)) == False)]
print (idx)

Index(['a'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

With list comprehension - updated based on Coldspeeds recommendation:

```
[x for x in df.index if not isinstance(x, float)]
```

Comment: This is in the right spirit, but you should always err on the side of using `isinstance` instead of doing an equality comparison on the `type`.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for the tip! Much appreciated. Is this better for performance?

Comment: It is considered better practice, and more pythonic.